# Multiple object in one Xml file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This is my Code

I can't serialize multiple objects in one XML File.

Create a new object in the main method and get input from the user to set all three attributes which reflect my own name and Id.
Serialize the object and store it in a XML file.

```
       System.String Degree_Program = System.String.Empty;
        public string degree
        { 
            get
            { return Degree_Program; }
            set
            { Degree_Program = value; }
        }
        public void student_Details()
        {
            System.Console.Write("Enter Your VUID:");
            VUID = System.Console.ReadLine();
            System.Console.Write("Enter Your Degree Program:");
            Degree_Program = System.Console.ReadLine();
        }


            static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Person person = new Person();
            Student student = new Student();

            person.person_details();
            student.student_Details();
            person.std_name = "ddheukd";
            student.Degree_Program = "Short Courses";
            student.VUID = "dksdjs";
            System.String filepath = @"A:\abcs.xml";

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filepath, false))



            System.Console.WriteLine("File Written Successfully!");
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it because you're missing the `android.` qualifier on the second line?

Comment: O yes ..I Got it :).. Thank u very much

Comment: Glad I could help! I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you forgot the `android.` qualifier in the second instance of `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`. The corrected version would read:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED 
    && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(DriverMap.this , new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```